# Why should I call File.Delete() through my own class?

Tags: .net, web-services, iis

In a VB.Net web service, inside several classes, I've found a lot of lines like this:

```
Dim sfile As New sFTP.Files
sfile.DeleteFile(strPath_to_File)
```

Besides, the code inside DeleteFile function is:

```
namespace sFTP
{
    public class Files
    {
        public void DeleteFile(string path)
        {
            try 
            {
                File.Delete(path);  
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 throw ex;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

What's the point of use a wrapper to call `File.Delete`? I've been told that shared classes could cause a bad IIS performance but File is, indeed, a shared class, so what is the advantage doing this?

Comment: Many reasons, e.g. abstraction (perhaps there may be different strategies for file deletion on Windows vs Linux). However, direct creation of the abstraction using `new` is not a good approach for this - it would be better to abstract `sFTP.Files` to implement an interface, and then also abstract the creation (e.g.. replace the direct call to `new` with a Factory pattern, IoC container dependency, or such). This will allow the actual deletion code to be Mocked out, for the purposes of Unit Testing, without actually needing to physically delete a file.

Comment: Why catch the exception and then rethrow it? Also: why rethrow it with `throw ex;` rather than `throw;`?

Comment: I'm sorry: it's a legacy code and I haven't enough experience in web development to give you an answer